# Blue smoke upon acceleration and pinking

Tags: fuel-system, nissan, exhaust

I have a Y12 Wingroad Nissan. While driving at 100km/hr and I stop, and begin driving again, I see a lot of blue smoke from exhaust for a little while. I also get a flat spot and pinking when accelerating. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate issues here.

First, you have what I would think is leaking valve seals. When you slow down, there is a great amount of vacuum build up inside the intake track. With leaking valve seals, this will pull oil past them and down into the intake track. This gets pulled into your engine when you speed back up and causes the blue smoke. Depending on the vehicle, this problem might be able to be handled without a major engine tear down, but who knows. Considering it's a small vehicle which probably has an over head cam, I would bet it will take some major tearing apart (head off the engine block) to get it done.

Second, it sounds like you need a tune up. The pinging might be due to carbon buildup due to burning oil which we looked at previously. Carbon buildup causes hotspots in your combustion chamber which allows the air/fuel mixture to ignite prior to when it's supposed to. You could try using some higher octane fuel, but that's expensive. You'll probably need an intake tract cleaning after the engine work I stated above to get it to stop.

Comment: PCV valve and hoses are also an item for your attention.